# Does Leaflet have corresponding components that can convert the data parsed by dxf into geojson?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, dxf

I plan to import cad files on the web and then use Leaflet to render an editable map. I have used dxf-parser to parse the dxf file, Is there any component of Leaflet that can convert dxf data into geojson?